# Deleting a single item from RecycleBin gives error "operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."

Tags: 2013, client-object-model, delete, recycle-bin

I have below code , but it gives mentioned error on `ExecuteQuery()` after `item.DeleteObject()`.

```
Site collSite1 = _ctx1.Site;
RecycleBinItemCollection collRBI1 = collSite1.RecycleBin;
_ctx1.Load(collRBI1);
_ctx1.ExecuteQuery();

RecycleBinItem item = collRBI1.SingleOrDefault(coll => coll.Id.ToString() == Id); //Here Id will have some value like "9aff6090-aecc-4342-a3a6-c2ecd957daee"

item.DeleteObject();
_ctx1.ExecuteQuery();
```

I also tried by putting this in web.config as per some solution in searching but failed.

```
add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="20000"
```

Any idea what this issue is about?

Comment: check this one http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c356c9af-0950-49d8-9b25-8bede9afa4cb/exception-when-deleting-other-people-items-in-sc-recycle-bin?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Comment: did you find any way?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to load `RecycleBinItem` collection, use [RecycleBinItemCollection.GetById method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.recyclebinitemcollection.getbyid(v=office.15).aspx) to get Recycle Bin item by the specified identifier from the collection.

The following example demonstrates how to find `RecycleBinItem` by identifier and delete it:

```
var recycleBinItemId = new Guid("recycle bin item guid");
var recycleBinItem = ctx.Site.RecycleBin.GetById(recycleBinItemId);
recycleBinItem.DeleteObject();
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Key points:

- Allows to delete `RecycleBinItem` using a single request to a server

Comment: Thanks Vadim for reply, I applied your given code but still it shows the same Error on ctx.ExecuteQuery().